# when I switch language to Arabic, the call log page does not display data

Tags: android, arabic, calllog, no-data

In my android project, when I switch language to Arabic, the call log page does not display data, but when I switch to other languages(such as english) can be displayed properly, how to solve, please see the following information.

1.A part of the code for the callLog adapter is as follows:

```
 //显示归属地
        if (callLog.getBelong_area() != null && !callLog.getBelong_area().equals("")) {
            LogE.e("item","有归属地："+callLog.getBelong_area());
            holder.belong_area.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.belong_area.setText(callLog.getBelong_area());
        } else {
            LogE.e("item","没有有归属地");
            holder.belong_area.setText("");
            holder.belong_area.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

2.It still does not display data when I enter a fixed value,such as follow:

```
holder.belong_area.setText("北京");
```

3.Print the log log as follows：

> 08-23 10:07:13.241 17494-17494/com.allinone.callerid E/item: 有归属地：北京
>   08-23 10:07:13.607 17494-17494/com.allinone.callerid E/item:
>   有归属地：Shijiazhuang,  Hebei 08-23 10:07:13.674
>   17494-17494/com.allinone.callerid E/item: 有归属地：北京 08-23 10:07:13.714
>   17494-17494/com.allinone.callerid E/item: 有归属地：湖北省，武汉市

4.Runtime screenshot：

arabic language(wrong),

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fxtY.jpg)

[english language(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxMsI.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxMsI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have proper character set of your system.

You can check the folowing code to detect a charaterset of the language.

```
public class CharsetDetectTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        detectCharset("北京");
    }

    public static void detectCharset(String originalStr) {

        String[] charSet 
          = { "utf-8", "big5", "EUC-CN", "iso-8859-1", "gb2312" };

        for (int i = 0; i < charSet.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < charSet.length; j++) {
                try {
                    LogE.e("charaters",
                        "[" + charSet[i] + "==>" + charSet[j] + "] = "
                        + new String(originalStr.getBytes(charSet[i]), charSet[j]));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The debug output will be

```
[utf-8==>utf-8] = 北京
[utf-8==>big5] = ��鈭�
[utf-8==>EUC-CN] = ��浜�
[utf-8==>iso-8859-1] = åäº¬
[utf-8==>gb2312] = ��浜�
[big5==>utf-8] = �_��
[big5==>big5] = 北京
[big5==>EUC-CN] = �_ㄊ
[big5==>iso-8859-1] = ¥_¨Ê
[big5==>gb2312] = �_ㄊ
[EUC-CN==>utf-8] = ����
[EUC-CN==>big5] = 控儔
[EUC-CN==>EUC-CN] = 北京
[EUC-CN==>iso-8859-1] = ±±¾©
[EUC-CN==>gb2312] = 北京
[iso-8859-1==>utf-8] = ??
[iso-8859-1==>big5] = ??
[iso-8859-1==>EUC-CN] = ??
[iso-8859-1==>iso-8859-1] = ??
[iso-8859-1==>gb2312] = ??
[gb2312==>utf-8] = ����
[gb2312==>big5] = 控儔
[gb2312==>EUC-CN] = 北京
[gb2312==>iso-8859-1] = ±±¾©
[gb2312==>gb2312] = 北京
```

Then, use one of the right characterset.

```
holder.belong_area.setText(new String("北京".getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8"));
```

or

```
holder.belong_area.setText(new String("北京".getBytes("utf-8"));
```

You can check the chinese charater [site](http://webcheatsheet.com/html/character_sets_list.php).

best regards,